# ERROR:syntax error at or near "%" in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Please i am trying to create a table in postgres using pgadmin. After selecting from the "Inherit from" drop down, i am getting the following error

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 2: INHERIT public.%22Staff%22;
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you take out the double quotes around `"Staff"`?

Comment: I cannot edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in pgAdmin4 as it doesn't appear to handle quoted object names, at least for inheritance.

I have now [reported this bug](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4985) to the PgAdmin community.

In the meantime, you may wish to take the SQL it generates (visible on the SQL tab) and manually edit then run it, replacing `%22` with `"`.  Or you could use table names without quoting, which will cause it to lose it's casing, so that may or may not be an issue for you.

Disclosure: I am an EnterpriseDB (EDB) employee.

Comment: You won't be able to edit the SQL in the SQL tab, but you can copy and paste it into the Query Editor.  That's the lightning bolt icon button on the main window, or go to Tools > Query Tool.